# React-native npm run android fails with following command on Mac m1

Tags: android, macos, react-native

React-native npm run android fails with following command on Mac m1

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

**.zshrc

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk  
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator  
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools  
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin   
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools  
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH  
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"**
```

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Comment: Did you once try to clean the Android project?
e.g. by running "cd android && ./gradlew clean"

Comment: First, your JAVA_HOME path is wrong, it must be `export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"`

Second, Have you installed the application on your emulator/physical device? If so, try uninstalling your app and rerun it

Comment: @LinhNguyễn tried changing java_home as per your advice still the error is same please help

Comment: Are you solve it?

Comment: @OliverD not yet

Answer (score 2):

After installing emulator and setting up development environment,
Run this command before Creating new project on m1 chip MacBook
**sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi**

I had same problem in my macbook air M1 and this command solved it
thanks